# Needing to update my outfile after items are changed

Tags: java, append, overwrite

For my program I have it set up that I can edit and change values of items that are stored within my outfile in the program itself. However the numbers that they change to only update in the program itself. For example if I sell 10 ketchups than in my program i would have 0 but my outfile would still say I have 10. I need my outfile to update with my program. I came up with an override method but all it does currently is adds content on a new line within the outfile, I am not sure how I would go about actually updating any information stored on the outfile any help would be great.

Code:

```
public class Driver {

public static ArrayList<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
static double myBalance = 100;
/*static ArrayList<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();*/


/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 * @throws FileNotFoundException 
 */



public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    ArrayList<String> inventoryList = new ArrayList<String>();

    BufferedReader readIn = null;
    try {
        readIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("inventory.out"));
        readIn.lines().forEach(inventoryList::add);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(readIn != null) {
            readIn.close();
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        String item = inventoryList.get(i);// input String like the one you would read from a file

        String delims = "[,]"; //delimiter - a comma is used to separate your tokens (name, qty,cost, price)

        String[] tokens = item.split(delims); // split it into tokens and place in a 2D array.

        String name = tokens[0]; System.out.println(name);

        double cost = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);System.out.println(cost);

        int qty = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);System.out.println(qty);

        double price = Double.parseDouble(tokens[3]);System.out.println(price);

        list.add(new Item(name, cost, qty, price));
    }

    sell("Mayo", 10);
    buy("Ketchup", 20);
    remove_item("Ketchup");
    add_item("Tums", 20, 10, 5);

    overwrite("New line");

    PrintAll();


}




// Method to sell items from the arraylist
public static void sell(String itemName, int amount) {


    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).getName().equals(itemName)) {
            int number = i;
            list.get(number).qty -= amount;
            myBalance += list.get(number).getPrice() * amount; 
        }
    }

}




// Method to buy more of the items in our array list
public static void buy(String itemName, int amount) {


    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).getName().equals(itemName)) {
            int number = i;
            list.get(number).qty += amount;
            myBalance -= list.get(number).getPrice() * amount; 
        }
    }
}



// Method to remove an item completely from our inventory
public static void remove_item(String itemName) {

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).getName().equals(itemName)) {
            int number = i;
            list.remove(number);
        }
    }
}


public static void add_item(String itemName, double itemCost, int qty, double itemPrice) {
    list.add(new Item(itemName, itemCost, qty, itemPrice));

    }


public static void PrintAll() {

    String output = "";
    for(Item i : list) {
        int everything = i.getQty();
        String everything2 = i.getName().toString();

        output += everything +" "+ everything2 + "\n";       
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your current balance is: $" + myBalance + "\n" + "Current stock:" + "\n" + output);

}


public static void overwrite(String update) {


    try
    {
        String filename= "inventory.out";
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename,true); //the true will append the new data
        fw.write("\n"+"add a line");//appends the string to the file
        fw.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        System.err.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
    }


}

}
```

Outfile contents:

```
Ketchup,1,10,2
Mayo,2,20,3
Bleach,3,30,4
Lysol,4,40,5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of your outfile then clear the outfile as and when you need it updated and then write to it again. You can use the below code to erase content of a file.

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
writer.print("");
writer.close();
```